# function getting wrong values

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

so i have this function in C to calculate a power, and i'm using visual c++ 2010

power.h

```
void power();  
float get_power(float a, int n);
```

power.c

```
void power()
{
    float a, r;
    int n;
    printf("-POWER-\n");
    printf("The base: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    n = -1;
    while (n < 0)
    {
        printf("The power: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("Power must be equal or larger than 0!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            r = get_power(a, n);
            printf("%.2f ^ %d = %.2f", a, n, r);
        }
    };
}

float get_power(float a, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
}
    return a * get_power(a, n-1);
}
```

not the best way to do it, i know, but that's not it
when i debug it the values are scanned correctly (that is, the values are correct until just before the function call) but then upon entering the function a becomes 0 and n becomes 1074790400, and you can guess what happens next...
the first function is being called from the main file, i included the full code because i really have no idea what could be going on, and i can't even think on how to google for it...
strangely, i wrote the function in a single file and it works fine, but it definitely should work both ways

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.  Are there any details you've omitted that might be messing things up?

Comment: This function works fine on my system. What are your input values?

Comment: not much more detail to omit, there is first.c which has main() and calls power() after having included it at the beginning using #include "power.h"

Comment: any input values i've tried (even 0) are scanned correctly and then dropped and changed for the other ones...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have

```
#include "power.h"
```

at the top of `power.c`?

If not, the compiler doesn't know what the prototype of `get_power()` is at the point of the call, so it will resort to promoting the first argument to a `double` instead of passing it as a `float`.  It'll also incorrectly assume that the result is an `int` instead of the `float` that's being returned.

If the compiler sees the prototype before the call, things will work better.

Comment: mmm that must be it... yeah, just included it and it works now... man i still can't get my head around headers... in this case, since the main c file and power.c are including power.h, do i have to guard it?

Comment: Yes.  I find it best to just use guards all the time.

Comment: You should *always* put include guards in headers as a matter of course, unless the header specifically needs them to not be there (like if you're doing some xmacro trickery). Though strictly speaking, if you just have function prototypes there's no problem with multiple inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pow` from `math.h`.
In other way you have error in multiplication in `get_power`, better write this on `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Was there a specific reason why you wanted to use recursion?

What about something simple like (untested):

```
float get_power(float a, int n)
{
    float result = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result = result * a;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i know, i used recursion just because, i do think iteration is simpler, but still the values passed are changed upon entering the function, so i would be getting the wrong behavior even if i just printed the values or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the existing answer, I ran this on xlc to see if it was a visual studio only problem. I got this answer:

```
"power.c", line 25.7: 1506-343 (S) Redeclaration of get_power differs from previous declaration on line 19 of "power.c".
"power.c", line 25.7: 1506-050 (I) Return type "float" in redeclaration is not compatible with the previous return type "int".
"power.c", line 25.7: 1506-379 (I) Prototype for function get_power must contain only promoted types if prototype and nonprototype declarations are mixed.
"power.c", line 25.7: 1506-380 (I) Parameter 1 has type "float" which promotes to "double".
```

I also tried it in a few other compilers I had around and got variations on this theme. You can see this as a warning in VS if you turn up the warning level.

So in conclusion, it SHOULDN'T compile, and VS is the only one that does compile and link it.